# What is the correct way to reference nested django apps in ManytoManyFields

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm trying to update an old django app from 1.1.x to 1.8 LTS, which has involved updating paths, as I apps move apps around.

However, I'm unable to generate migrations for one app, and I can't see how to reference a namespaced app model correctly (assuming that's the problem)

If I've moved files from PROJECT/news/models to  PROJECT/site_name/news/models, how should I be referencing these models in in foreign keys or ManyToManyFields?

## My app

I have a `projects` app I want to make migrations for. Projects in `some_org/projects`, and listed in installed apps like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'some_org.maps',
    'some_org.library',
    'some_org.extras',
    'some_org.news',
    'some_org.projects',
    'some_org.members',
    'some_org.comments',
)
```

All the apps with the namespace are within the `some_org` directory.

Here's an abridged view of the models file in the projects app:

```
# some_org/projects/models.py

from some_org.library import Paper


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def get_children(self):
        return ProjectPage.objects.filter(level=1, publish=True, project=self)

    def has_library(self):
        return Paper.objects.filter(projects=self).count() > 0
```

Calling ./manage.py makemigrations library, gives me this error:

```
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field library.Paper.projects: projects.Project
```

When I look in the Paper model, it looks like this:

```
class Paper(models.Model):

# snip

# NewsLinkSubject, Projects et al used to in an app on 
# the project root, like `./app_name/models.py`, but is now 
# in `some_org/app_name/models.py`

subjects = models.ManyToManyField("news.NewsLinkSubject", blank=True)
projects = models.ManyToManyField("projects.Project", blank=True,)
country =  models.ForeignKey("maps.Country", null=True, blank=True)
```

I initially wonder if the label for the app is wrong, and try the projects ManytoMany field to:

```
projects = models.ManyToManyField("some_org.projects.Project", blank=True,)
```

This gives a different error:

```
ERRORS:
library.Paper.subjects: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model some_org.projects.Project', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

As far as I can tell the app is installed, and the models aren't abstract.

I'm pretty stumped - what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this so I can make migrations for these apps?

I'm using Django 1.8.17, and Python 2.7.13.

Answer (score 0):

You should define an `app_label` in the Meta class for your models. Whatever you put in there becomes the first part of the name you use in the ManyToManyField definition.

Comment: Why would that help? when I run something like `./manage.py migrate --list library` the library app is being recognised as 'library' - wouldn't adding the app_label be redundant?